# Vue create component in same component

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vue-cli

I have a quick question that I can't find an answer for. I have a problem.

I have a component SelectForm.vue (it is a form with buttons), and now I want on button click in this SelectForm.vue component, to make another SelectForm below it. Is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a wrapper component that shows all `SelectForm` components.  When the button is clicked on the first form, `emit` an event, listen for it in the wrapper, and create a new one there.

```
Vue.component('Wrapper', {
    template: `<div>
        <SelectForm v-for="(form, index) in numForms" @new="numForms++" />
    </div>`,
    data() {
        return {
            numForms: 1
        }
    }
})

Vue.component('SelectForm', {
    template: `<div>
        The Form<br />
        <button @click="$emit('new')">Duplicate</button>
    </div>`
});

new Vue({
    el: "#app"
})
```

Here is a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sh0ber/nhqmtf9a/)

Answer (score 1):

If a component must render itself, Vue does allow recursive components.

https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-edge-cases.html#Recursive-Components